# Why do some html pages get distorted when they are saved and opened offline?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

[image]I am trying to save a page of http://leetcode.com/ site. I did Ctrl+S on the intended page. 
But when I tried to open the saved page in browser, the alignment changed, and spacing is no more proper between paras and headings. Why do this happen ? 
I tried saving many pages from lot of other site and didn't face any problem at all. What is that things in http://leetcode.com/ site that has made it so ?

Comment: Try to save it as .mht file (IE and others that support it).  It puts all the resources in one file.

Comment: Did you just try? I did, but IE opens it as a text file with all the html codes on window. Or Am I missing something ?

Comment: You save it as .htm.  Wrong...you want .mht format.  Do a save as and and choose .mht instead of .htm.  here's a link about it [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML)

Comment: Glad it worked.  I'm going to paste the comment into an answer so you can mark it as "answer."  This way, this post has some kind of resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Zuzlx.(read comments on question).
We can save the page in .mht format. Do a save as and and choose .mht instead of .htm.

Reason for improper display in .html file may be because we are not able to download all the files. (see Dryden Long's answer for those files).

Comment: Flag in Chrome? Please show some more light. I tried searching it, but could get much help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not downloading all of the site's resources. You need to download all of the site's CSS and Javascript files. Also, if the site is using any server-side scripting, you will not be able to download that and it will cause problems as well.

When I save the website you mentioned and look into the console it gives me this:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/themes/buddyboss/_inc/css/default.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/themes/buddyboss/_inc/css/buddybar.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/themes/buddyboss/_inc/css/auto.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/themes/buddyboss/_inc/css/custom.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/themes/buddyboss-child/_inc/css/custom.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/plugins/collapsing-archives/img/list-expand.gif
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/js/fancybox/fancybox_sprite.png
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///C:/wp-content/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/js/fancybox/fancybox_loading.gif
```

Comment: Is there a method to save that page, and view it in the same way as its online ? (you can see the image that I have added just now (above))

Comment: View the page source and download all of the available resources. You may have to edit the source code to coincide with your document structure. Also, any server-side files will not be available to you, so if the site uses those you're out of luck.

Comment: if you just want it to LOOK the same, right click the page background, press [CRTL]+[A], [COPY], then paste into a contentEditable div, and save the div.innerHTML.

Comment: @dandavis : You may be correct. But I think saving it as .mht format makes it look the same when opened offline.

Comment: Firefox, in particular, has an issue saving all the resources associated with a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save it as .mht file (IE and others that support it). It puts all the resources in one file